# How to comment enclosing tag ? - Wrap/Comment

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have an HTML container tag with contents in it.  How can I comment the container tag without commenting the content?

WebStorm has the wrap/remove enclosing tag. Does something like wrap/comment exist?

For instance if you have a pair of nested divs  `<div id='outer'><p id='inner'>Lorem ipsum ...</p></div>`

Is there any command (shortcut key) that would allow me to comment out the outer div without commenting the inner paragraph?

Comment: There is no such functionality, unfortunately .... Maybe some 3rd party plugins has it .. but I personally do not know any.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any shortcut like that you still have to do something like  this

```html
<!--<div id='outer'>-->
     <p id='inner'>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
<!--</div>-->
```

/div>-->